# How to insert multiple photos and multiple text fields into mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Plain and simple. I want to create a form that first of all inserts all fields values into the MySQL database. Second of all, I want to give users options to upload multiple images. but the code below wont insert image into the database. I am totally lost. don't know what else might be wrong with this code.

```
   <form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p> 
            <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p> 
            <p><input type="file" name="file_array[]"></p> 
            <input type="FirstN" name="Firstname" >
            <input type="LastN" name="Lastname" >

        <input type="submit" value="Upload all files">

    </form>


<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])) { 
        $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name']; 
        $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name']; 
        $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type']; 
        $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size']; 
        $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error']; 
        for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++) { 
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "test_uploads/".$name_array[$i])) {  
            echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>"; 
            } else { 
            echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>"; 
                   } 
            }
        }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO image, FirstName, LastName VALUES ('{FirstN}','{LastN}','{file_array}')"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: You are aware of course that the easier and more efficient way is to store the file in the file system or the cloud and just to save the reference to the file in the database?

Comment: @e4c5 yeah like right now I am saving the file in the file directory but just storing the name in the mysql but still having trouble with submitting every field all at once. What I mean is that if user uploads the file, I want no upload button but instead I want them to fill out rest of the form and with one click on submit, I want everything submitted to the database.

Comment: You need to break this up into two smaller problems. First work on getting file upload working. Then work on the PHP code to create database records separately. And when they both work independently, combine the two.

Comment: You'll want to run the MySQL in the loop to INSERT like you want. Of course, you have to use valid MySQL.

Comment: @PHPglue whats invalid about my code? thanks.

Comment: You need to do an `INSERT` at each step of the loop. Also, it's more like: `"INSERT image (FirstName, LastName, FileName) VALUES('{$_POST['FirstName']}','{$_POST['LastName']}','$name_array[$i]')";`.